# EF Core 3 issues with .Include() when using .AsExpandable()

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, c#-3.0

I've migrated concepts from a couple of CQRS frameworks I've seen and just started facing some issues.

I have a common EntityDbContext subclass which I use in any consuming project without further extension to suit the domain of the application, rather I provide interfaces, IReadEntities and IWriteEntities which have methods like Query() and Get() which behind the scenes call Set() returning the DbSet() then allowing the standard LINQ expressions to be chained on as for any EF query. I'm facing issues around using Include() on my IQueryables as I'm using LinqKit with AsExpandable() at the end of all my calls. This is what my context Query methods look like

```
public new IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    // AsNoTracking returns entities that are not attached to the DbContext
    return QueryUnfiltered<TEntity>().Where(_recordAuthority.Clause<TEntity>());
}

public IQueryable<TEntity> QueryUnfiltered<TEntity>() where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    // AsNoTracking returns entities that are not attached to the DbContext
    return Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().AsExpandable();
}
```

A typical query handler looks like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<GetCustomerView>> Handle(CustomersBy query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var customers = _db.Query<Customer>();

    // Apply filters
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.FirstName))
        customers = customers.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(query.FirstName));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.LastName))
        customers = customers.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(query.LastName));

    // Execute the query and return the results
    var view = await customers.Select(x => new GetCustomerView
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        FirstName = x.FirstName,
        LastName = x.LastName,
        EmailAddress = x.EmailAddress
    }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false) as IEnumerable<GetCustomerView>;

    return view;
}
```

This scenario works fine if I wanted to pull address details from a related table as I use projection on the database serve given I'm using the Select prior to execution. There are scenarios though where it makes sense to pull an object graph back and specify Include(...) statements but as it stands specifying `_db.Query<Customer>().Include(c => c.Address)` doesn't hydrate the Address navigation property. I've tried leaving the AsExpandable() off and then the results come back.

The question is, does anyone see a way to allow the Include statements to be provided maybe as a parameter to the method and then I loop through them and tack them on before calling AsExpandable()? I can't quite get my head around how to do it, if it's possible.

Maybe there's another approach?

Interestingly this apparently works fine on a version of this pattern a colleague uses where they are using EF 6. He says they specify Include after the AsExpandable without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue with EF Core and LinqKit `AsExpandable` (and in general with any extension library which uses custom `IQueryProvider` to perform its query expression tree preprocessing like LinqKit), because EF Core ignores all EF Core specific `IQueryable` extensions (`Include` / `ThenInclude`, `AsNoTracking` etc.) it the query provider is different (or does not inherit) the EF Core one (EF6 has no such requirements).

With that being said, currently there is no other solution than applying all EF Core specific extensions *before* calling `AsExpandable`.

Comment: Cool thanks for the details. I'm interested though in how I might inject the Include prior to the AsExpandable given my Query methods. I was thinking I could take a parameter that is a list of includes or whatever they break down to, perhaps `IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> includes) where TEntity : class, IEntity` then loop through and tack on Include statements. I started this but wasn't sure what lambda to build. `Expression<Func<Customer, Address>> blah = (c, a) => c.Address;` doesn't seem to compile

Comment: Oh, I'm dopey this is correct `Expression<Func<Customer, Address>> blah = c => c.Address;`

Comment: If you don't need `ThenInclude`, `params Expression<T, object>[] includes` as usual for EF6 would work. Otherwise you need something like `Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> includes = null`. You can find this in other SO answers, including mine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this works. I created an overload:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity, TProperty>(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>> includes) where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    var query = Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();

    foreach (var expression in includes)
    {
        query = query.Include(expression);
    }

    return query.AsExpandable();
}
```

From my handler I create a list of include expressions and pass to the Query:

```
var includes = new List<Expression<Func<Customer, object>>>
{
    c => c.Address
};

var customers = _db.Query(includes);
var result = await customers.ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Execution of the query has the navigation property populated:
[image]

Means I'm not 'Fluent'ly chaining them from the client code's perspective, but I don't think it's terrible.

Thoughts?